# is it possible to deploy scanners with group policy or any other solution

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, group-policy

we are a company of 60 employees/computers and want all employees to be able to scan, we purchased a Brother MFC-L2700DW and connected it with ethernet to network i'm able to scan just fine by adding the scanner in computer under the network section.

is there a way to deploy them with group policy just like you can deploy printers?
or if this isn't possible is there any other suggestion without having to go to each computer and manually adding them?

all computers here are running windows 7 pro.

(we've added all the printers to a printer running server 2008 and deployed them with group policy, i've also added scan management as a server role and added the scanner)

is it possible to deploy scanners with group policy or any other solution?

if anyone can offer I'd greatly appreciate it.

also i'm a newbie in IT in general and haven't used serverfault a lot either.

Comment: I wouldn't bother.  Set up scan-to-email or scan-to-file and put the file share somewhere everyone can access it.

Comment: @BlueCompute Thank you for your help. That's what I've done and works.

Comment: If that works for you I'll make that a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in group policy for deploying scanners, unlike printers.  Using group policy you could push a software package to each client PC if you're using the manufacturers proprietary scanning utility.  I haven't investigated pushing the TWAIN scanner drivers and modifying the registry to add the relevant scanners to Windows Fax and Scan - that would be a labour-intensive way of rolling your own scanner GPO.

A simple alternative is to set up either scan-to-email and add the user's email addresses, or to set up scan-to-file (CIFS / SMB) and set up a scans folder on a shared drive that all users have access to, or for more security separate scan folders for each user.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've set up scan to file on a shared folder.